# efficient way to check a stack of unempty properties

Tags: php, oop

I have a *sample* class like this

```
class foo{
  private $a = null; 
  private $b = null; 
  private $c = null; 
  private $d = null; 

 function a(){$a = ''; return $this; }
 function b(){$b = '0'; return $this; }
 function c(){$c = 'x';  return $this;  }
 function d(){$d = 'false';  return $this; }

 function z(){
    //I would like to only echo properties that are not null. 
    //and I am looking for better alternative than using if/else approach. 
  }
}
```

This is how I like to call the methods.

```
$o = new foo(); 
$o->a()
  ->b()
  ->c()
  ->d()
  -z();
```

So, now the method `z()` should echo properties that are not null. Since I have many properties, using if/else would prove to be difficult/verbose.

Comment: One way would be to convert your properties to a local array inside that class. The benefit would be being able to use array_filter() which will return an array minus the empty keys in the original array. http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php

Comment: @kuroineko http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21050862/efficient-way-to-check-a-stack-of-unempty-properties#comment31651251_21050976

Answer (score 0):

In your class, you can use [`get_object_vars()`](http://php.net/get_object_vars) to get the properties available in the current scope:

```
function z()
{
  foreach (get_object_vars($this) as $key => $value)
  {
    if (is_null($value))
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a very good approach. Thanks. But, as I tried it, it taken into account any assignment property made inside the constructor. In other words, it takes `$this->a` in this case `function __construct($foo){$this->a = $foo;}` as a property.

Comment: @user2679413 I'm not sure what you want, if you need to check against the default values, you can use `get_class_vars(foo)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over `$this` which will give you the property name and value via `foreach ($this as $key=>$value)` - and there you can easily use `empty()`

See [this working example](http://3v4l.org/ZKTmp).

```
public function echoAllProperties() {
    foreach ($this as $key=>$value) {
        if (!empty($value))
            echo $key." => ".$value."\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    $o = new foo();

    $class_vars = get_class_vars(get_class($o));

    foreach ($class_vars as $name => $value) {
        echo "$name : $value\n";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:

It seems you are using your own definition of what a PHP object property is, so let me give you mine.

The PHP doc is a bit fuzzy about the subject, and some functions like `get_object_vars` are a bit misleading since they will get object properties and not variables.

As far as I understand it, what it boils down to is: PHP makes a distinction between ***class* properties** (known at compile time), and ***dynamic* properties** (the ones that are set without having been declared).

It has something to do with setting a property (since it will create a dynamic one), but the main point is to know whether the properties were declared as such inside the class definition or not.

If it is indeed this difference between class and object properties that interests you, you might find happiness with the `ReflectionClass` API, though I find it awkward to the extreme to use, if you ask me.

The main advantage of this API is that you can list properties that would be inaccessable from your current scope (typically a protected or private member).
If you simply use the `get_object_vars` or `get_class_vars` functions, you will miss all the private/protected properties unless you define a method inside the object itself (inheriting a class that calls `get_class_vars` will allow you to get the protected properties, but not the private ones).

```
function list_properties($obj, $filter = null)
{
    if ($filter === null) $filter = ReflectionProperty::IS_STATIC 
                                  | ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC 
                                  | ReflectionProperty::IS_PROTECTED 
                                  | ReflectionProperty::IS_PRIVATE;

    $spy = new ReflectionClass ($obj);
    $class_properties = $spy->getProperties($filter);

    echo "class:<br />";
    foreach ($class_properties as $prop)
    {
        $name = $prop->getName();
        $p = $spy->getProperty ($name);
        $p->setAccessible(true);
        $value = $p->getValue($obj);
        echo "$name ("; var_dump($value); echo ")<br />";
    }
    echo "<br />object:<br />";
    foreach ($obj as $property => $value)
        { echo "$property ("; var_dump($value); echo ")<br />"; }
}

class foo {
    protected $class_protected; 
    private   $class_private; 
    public    $class_public; 
    private static $static_protected = "azerty";
    private static $static_private   = "qsdfgh";
    public  static $static_public    = "wxcvbn";
}


$v = new foo();
$v->dynamic = "xxx";
list_properties($v);

// the ReflectionClass filter flags semantic is broken,
// so filtering becomes soon a cruel pain in the *ss
/*
 * I leave it to the reader as an execrise to coax the bloody thing
 * into giving you only the static public class properties, for instance.
 */
list_properties($v, ReflectionProperty::IS_STATIC|ReflectionProperty::IS_PUBLIC);
```

Comment: Problem is that is take vars initialized in the constructor.

Comment: ??? it takes properties with their current values. There are no variables in this code except $v, $property and $value.

Comment: I am saying, whatever is defined inside the constructor is assumed a property, and I did not want that

Comment: in function a(){$a=''; retrun $this;} use $this->a = '' not $a= ''

Comment: @Surace Yeah, that was a mistake. But, I think everyone has gotten the message